# Optimizing cohort analysis on Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I'm attempting to perform a cohort analysis on a very large table. I have a test table with ~30M rows (over double in production). The query fails in BigQuery stating "resources exceeded.." and it's a tier 18 query (tier 1 is $5, so it's a $90 query!)

The query:

```
with cohort_active_user_count as (
  select 
    DATE(`BQ_TABLE`.created_at, '-05:00') as created_at,
    count(distinct`BQ_TABLE`.bot_user_id) as count,
    `BQ_TABLE`.bot_id as bot_id
  from `BQ_TABLE`
  group by created_at, bot_id
)

select created_at, period as period,
  active_users, retained_users, retention, bot_id
from (
  select 
    DATE(`BQ_TABLE`.created_at, '-05:00') as created_at,
    DATE_DIFF(DATE(future_message.created_at, '-05:00'), DATE(`BQ_TABLE`.created_at, '-05:00'), DAY) as period,
    max(cohort_size.count) as active_users, -- all equal in group
    count(distinct future_message.bot_user_id) as retained_users,
    count(distinct future_message.bot_user_id) / max(cohort_size.count) as retention,
    `BQ_TABLE`.bot_id as bot_id
  from `BQ_TABLE`
  left join `BQ_TABLE` as future_message on
    `BQ_TABLE`.bot_user_id = future_message.bot_user_id
    and `BQ_TABLE`.created_at < future_message.created_at
    and TIMESTAMP_ADD(`BQ_TABLE`.created_at, interval 720 HOUR) >= future_message.created_at
    and `BQ_TABLE`.bot_id = future_message.bot_id 
  left join cohort_active_user_count as cohort_size on 
    DATE(`BQ_TABLE`.created_at, '-05:00') = cohort_size.created_at
    and `BQ_TABLE`.bot_id = cohort_size.bot_id 
  group by 1, 2, bot_id) t
where period is not null
and bot_id = 80
order by created_at, period, bot_id
```

Here is the desired output:

[image]

From my understanding of BigQuery, the joins are causing a major performance hit because each BigQuery node needs to process them. The table is partitioned by day, which I'm not yet making use of in this query, but I know it will still need to be optimized.

How can this query be optimized or exclude the use of joins to allow BigQuery to process more efficiently in parallel?

Comment: Do you have a job ID for the failed query? A BigQuery engineer may be able to give suggestions on how to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Step #1

Try below
Moved JOIN'ing on `cohort_active_user_count` outside the inner `SELECT` as I think it is one of main reason for query be expensive. And as you see - using JOIN instead LEFT JOIN for this one as LEFT is not needed here

Please test and let us know result

```
WITH cohort_active_user_count AS (
  SELECT 
    DATE(BQ_TABLE.created_at, '-05:00') AS created_at,
    COUNT(DISTINCT BQ_TABLE.bot_user_id) AS COUNT,
    BQ_TABLE.bot_id AS bot_id
  FROM BQ_TABLE
  GROUP BY created_at, bot_id
)
SELECT t.created_at, period AS period,
  cohort_size.count AS active_users, retained_users, 
  retained_users / cohort_size.count AS retention, t.bot_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DATE(BQ_TABLE.created_at, '-05:00') AS created_at,
    DATE_DIFF(DATE(future_message.created_at, '-05:00'), DATE(BQ_TABLE.created_at, '-05:00'), DAY) AS period,
    COUNT(DISTINCT future_message.bot_user_id) AS retained_users,
    BQ_TABLE.bot_id AS bot_id
  FROM BQ_TABLE
  LEFT JOIN BQ_TABLE AS future_message 
    ON BQ_TABLE.bot_user_id = future_message.bot_user_id
    AND BQ_TABLE.created_at < future_message.created_at
    AND TIMESTAMP_ADD(BQ_TABLE.created_at, interval 720 HOUR) >= future_message.created_at
    AND BQ_TABLE.bot_id = future_message.bot_id 
  GROUP BY 1, 2, bot_id
  HAVING period IS NOT NULL
) t
JOIN cohort_active_user_count AS cohort_size 
  ON t.created_at = cohort_size.created_at
  AND t.bot_id = cohort_size.bot_id 
WHERE t.bot_id = 80
ORDER BY created_at, period, bot_id
```

> Step # 2

Below "further optimization" is based on assumption that your BQ_TABLE is a raw data with multiple entries for the same user_id/bit_id for the same day - thus increasing a lot expenses of LEFT JOIN in inner SELECT.
I propose first to aggregate this, as it is done below. In addition to drastically reducing size of JOIN - it also eliminates all those conversion from TIMESTAMP to DATE in each join'ed row

```
WITH BQ_TABLE_AGG AS (
  SELECT bot_id, bot_user_id, DATE(BQ_TABLE.created_at, '-05:00') AS created_at
  FROM BQ_TABLE
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
),
cohort_active_user_count AS (
  SELECT 
    created_at,
    COUNT(DISTINCT bot_user_id) AS COUNT,
    bot_id AS bot_id
  FROM BQ_TABLE_AGG
  GROUP BY created_at, bot_id
)
SELECT t.created_at, period AS period,
  cohort_size.count AS active_users, retained_users, 
  retained_users / cohort_size.count AS retention, t.bot_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    BQ_TABLE_AGG.created_at AS created_at,
    DATE_DIFF(future_message.created_at, BQ_TABLE_AGG.created_at, DAY) AS period,
    COUNT(DISTINCT future_message.bot_user_id) AS retained_users,
    BQ_TABLE_AGG.bot_id AS bot_id
  FROM BQ_TABLE_AGG
  LEFT JOIN BQ_TABLE_AGG AS future_message 
    ON BQ_TABLE_AGG.bot_user_id = future_message.bot_user_id
    AND BQ_TABLE_AGG.created_at < future_message.created_at
    AND DATE_ADD(BQ_TABLE_AGG.created_at, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= future_message.created_at
    AND BQ_TABLE_AGG.bot_id = future_message.bot_id 
  GROUP BY 1, 2, bot_id
  HAVING period IS NOT NULL
) t
JOIN cohort_active_user_count AS cohort_size 
  ON t.created_at = cohort_size.created_at
  AND t.bot_id = cohort_size.bot_id 
WHERE t.bot_id = 80
ORDER BY created_at, period, bot_id
```

Comment: @mnort9 - did you have chance to try?

Comment: This works excellent, thanks! I had figured out using an aggregate was the way to go, but additionally removing the timestamp conversion reduced the query from ~60 secs to ~11 secs. Once I utilize the partition time, it should be pretty speedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to enable a higher billing tier given the costs, here are a couple of suggestions that might help to reduce the CPU requirements:

- Use `INNER JOIN`s rather than `LEFT JOIN`s if you can. `INNER JOIN`s should generally be less CPU-intensive, but then again you won't get unmatched rows like you would with `LEFT JOIN`s.
- Use `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(expr)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT expr`). You won't get an exact count, but it's less CPU-intensive and may be "good enough" depending on your needs.

You could also consider manually breaking the query into stages of computation, e.g. write the `WITH` clause statement to a table, then use that in the subsequent query. I don't know what the specific cost tradeoffs would be, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it tagged MySQL?

In MySQL, I would change

```
max(cohort_size.count) as active_users, -- all equal in group
```

to

```
( SELECT max(count) FROM cohort_active_user_count WHERE ... ) as active_users,
```

and remove the `JOIN` to that table.  Without doing this, you risk inflating the `COUNT(...)` values!

Also move the division to get `retention` into the outside query.

Once you have done that, you can also move the other `JOIN` into a subquery:

```
( SELECT count(distinct future_message.bot_user_id)
    FROM ... WHERE ... ) as retained_users,
```

I would have these indexes.  Note that `created_at` needs to be last.

```
cohort_active_user_count:  INDEX(bot_id, created_at)
future_message: (bot_id, bot_user_id, created_at)
```